# Can we call JSON POST API from VB.NET Windows App?

Tags: vb.net

Here I am always getting "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.". Even the API is correct and working nicely through POSTMAN and in other languages also. Please guide me so solve this issue. I am attaching the function which is calling the API directly.

```
Private Function SendRequest() As String
    Dim response As String
    Dim request As WebRequest
    Dim encoding As New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
    Dim uri = ""
    Dim Tran = "15"
    Dim Amount As Integer = 1000
    Dim ReferenceID = "015bfa15-15ec-4dc7-903c-053ffacb6688"
    Dim POS = "57290070"
    Dim Store = "RESTSIM00000001"
    Dim Chain = "J@P-Reg"
   
    Dim JSONString = "{""tran"":""" & Tran & """,""amount"":""" & Amount & """,""reference"":""" & ReferenceID & """,""pos"":""" & POS & """,""store"":""" & Store & """,""chain"":""" & Chain & """}"
    Dim jsonDataBytes() As Byte = encoding.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JSONString))
    request = WebRequest.Create(uri)
    request.ContentLength = jsonDataBytes.Length
    request.ContentType = "application/json"
    request.Method = "POST"

    Using requestStream = request.GetRequestStream
        requestStream.Write(jsonDataBytes, 0, jsonDataBytes.Length)
        requestStream.Close()

        Using responseStream = request.GetResponse.GetResponseStream
            Using reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
                response = reader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Return response
End Function
```

Comment: A 500 error is an error from the API itself. Something has thrown an unhandled error on the API side (possibly the data you are sending). I take it you removed the `uri` value for sanitisation? Is there a very simple test API method that you can possibly call?

Comment: There is no error in sending Data. I have removed URI due to security. Can you help me out in the above function which I have written or suggest me better code to Call JSON API?

Comment: Point your Postman to a [Hookbin endpoint](https://hookbin.com/), then point your vb.net app to that endpoint, compare what it actually got.

Comment: Yeah Everything is Working. I want to know whether VB.NET can directly call JSON API? That is what I am facing. I can successfully call this API in C# and Flutter. But unable to do it in vb.net

Comment: Yes vb.net can call a Json API (I also pretty sure there really is no such thing as a Json api, but for the sake of the question...).  As @Nick.McDermaid said.  a 500 error is at the server end.   Likely hood is something in your Json payload is out of whack.  I always get a little concerned when seeing strings concatenated like that.  Have you checked JSONString is valid befor serializing it and the output of  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JSONString) to ensure it's valid?

Comment: Do you have control of the server side? You need to find out what's failing there. As already mentioned, the issue is most likely some string escape character/concatenation issue - you aren't quite posting the same thing that you are via the other methods.

Comment: Have you tried printing `JSONString` and confirming it is valid JSON? If you are doing freeform concatenation like that, don't even bother asking a question here until you have printed, inspected, and validated your dynamic string.

Comment: For example you are concatenating an `Integer` (`Amount`) to a string in your code. Are you certain you know what that is producing?

Comment: I have done everything before asking here. I have printed the JSONString and use it on POSTMan. And it working fine. Even I created Object and Then make JSONString. This method also not working

Comment: Just as some background, the web API has no idea what is calling it, it's just accepting a post from something. Does your postman request have any special headers? Because there are no headers set up in this code

Comment: Perhaps you could start from basics. Are you able to call this public test API from vb.net: `https://reqres.in/api/users/2`. It doesn't require a payload, just a `GET`

Comment: When you say you did everything, did you try the hookbin endpoint as suggested in an earlier comment?

Comment: I tried your code out and the resulting JSON looks correct. Are you certain that amount should be surrounded by quotes though? Maybe you should try `"amount":1000` instead of `"amount":"1000"`